# How to retrieve a complete directory from a URL

Tags: command-line, browser, download, recursive, tree

Is there a method on Windows or Linux for downloading all files* within an online directory, specifically:

http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/

so I have a local repository I can work on? Any browser or command-line solutions would be fine, and I am willing to download any browser.

*recursively

Comment: Not a duplicate of the question, since I asked what to do about downloading the files, not how to use the syntax of ```wget```. Though they may share a single common solution the questions are very much not the same e.g. there are possibly other solutions not involving ```wget```.

Comment: _The question doesn't ask for software recommendations_, it asks for a solution. If people suggest software that's up to them, but if you read the question that's not what it's doing.

Comment: No it's not. Not all solutions involve software recommendations.

Comment: There is no currently available comment regarding google searchability. Suggest moving to chat or meta to resolve as this doesn't appear to be a constructive dialogue at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38443/discussion-between-peter-david-carter-and-karel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` has a feature specifically designed for this need.  The command you need would be:

```
wget --no-parent -r http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/
```

`-r` means recursive.
`--no-parent` would skip the "Parent directory" link. Without this, the siblings of `tumbleweed` will also get downloaded.

Comment: Weirdly, I keep getting a '404' error for some of the files but I don't understand how that's possible. Surely ```wget``` should only be attempting to get the files that are actually in the directory? It seems to be reattempting, but something doesn't feel quite right...